# Cobol Read statement format. Can it be redone a different way?

Tags: cobol

On this read statement below couldn't it be made into the form of the following? I think personaly it might be easier to understand and read.

Basically the read statement is simply reading through a file and making decision on which paragraph performs should be executed. It probably is difficult to see exaclty what the program does but what I was really interested to know was if you can change the read to a different format as listed below.

READ DATA-FILE
  AT END
     ...do some code
  NOT AT END
     ...do code that is below
END-READ.

Class:

```
    INIT-READ.                                            
    READ C AT END                                
            GO TO EOJ.                                
    IF C-ID = '  ' AND C-S = 'P'            
       GO TO I-R                                
    END-IF.                                           
    IF CID = ' ' AND C-S = 'D'             
       IF F = 'Y'                                   
          MOVE 'N' TO F                             
          MOVE 'your text here' TO RPT-ID 
          MOVE A           TO H6                  
          MOVE B           TO H7                  
          PERFORM PA THRU H-A-X             
       END-IF                                         
          PERFORM WD-CLAIM THRU W-X            
       GO TO I-R                                
    END-IF.                                           
          PERFORM N-V THRU N-V-X.
```

Comment: With all those GOTO statements and PERFORM THRU ranges its kind of hard to figure out what might be going on here anyway. I would sort that mess out first, and then restructure the READ statement. Yes you can specify both types of AT END clauses in the same READ statement: `READ C AT END PERFORM X NOT AT END PERFORM Y END-READ`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of a discussion thread, captured in the GNU Cobol FAQ, http://opencobol.add1tocobol.com/gnucobol/#performing-forever Roger While mentioned a pretty nice idiom for READ control without paragraphs.

> One thing that I saw on earlier posts to
>   the newsgroup cobol was
>
> What is the need/justification for an
>   empty inline perform group.
>
> ie.
>     PERFORM
>     ...
>     END-PERFORM
>
> None of the discussions then realized that
>   there is a -
>   EXIT PERFORM [CYCLE]
>
> Therefore, it is a method to to
>   define an exit condition without having paragraphs.
>
> ie. (very simply)

```
PERFORM
    READ xxx
      AT END
        EXIT PERFORM
    END-READ
    MOVE something TO somewhere
END-PERFORM

.. test xxx status and somewhere
```

> There are, of course, other variations.
>   Basically, it means that you code without
>   using section/paragraphs.
>   (Recommended, if only from performance point of view)
>
> Note that the CYCLE option offers interesting possibilities.
>
> Roger

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but the `PERFORM` loop illustrated above is a GNU COBOL extention only. I think Microfocus Managed COBOL has a similar extention too. However, this is not something found in the COBOL 85 or 2002 ANSI Standards for COBOL.

Comment: Is there any way to get a version of Cobol for PC. I had a book that had a diskette in it but I never could get it to work. How is the Visual Cobol?

Comment: @DougHauf for trial/personal versions of Micro Focus COBOL, see www.microfocus.com. For a free and very full-featured alternative with an active community of expounders (including Brian) see GNU COBOL at SourceForge.

Comment: @NealB; yeah a little ahead, but it's in the next Draft, 14.9.27.3 subentry 6.  `6) A PERFORM statement without times-phrase, until-phrase, or varying-phrase is the basic PERFORM statement.
  The specified set of statements referenced by this type of PERFORM statement is executed once and then
 control passes to the end of the PERFORM statement.
`

Comment: I used `PERFORM UNTIL (0 = 1)` once, because back then I didn't know about a `PERFORM` without anything.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here. [COBOL read/store in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985579/cobol-read-store-in-table/19991896#19991896). for a way of avoiding GO TO, and even the AT END/NOT AT END. No END-READ needed either.

To avoid the AT END/NOT AT END, simply use the File Status, which you should already be using anyway to check that all IO operations were successful. For an input file, READ will give a file status of 10 when end-of-file is detected.

Use an 88 on your file status. So you can say things like END-OF-PAYMENTS-TRANSACTIONS.

Then, to process your file, you use a "priming read". This is a read outside the loop.

```
priming read
processing-loop until END-OF-PAYMENTS-TRANSACTIONS
   do the processing
   read
```

EXIT PERFORM (and some other EXIT options) is not available in all COBOLs currently. Be aware that if you are part of a large team and put an EXIT PERFORM in your program you will likely find several EXIT PERFORMs in the same block of code within a couple of years. So they may have well been GO TOs all along. The new EXIT options are just a way of have a GO TO which is spelled differently. OK, a little tongue-in-cheek, but there we go.

Of course, the priming read and read above both PERFORM a single paragraph to do the actual read and check the validity of the io (file status zero or 10 is OK, else a problem).

Be careful about considering avoiding PERFORM paragraph/SECTION for "performance". Write for clarity unless performance is critical. With IBM's Enterprise COBOL, using OPT, PERFORM code can be "inlined" anyway.

Comment: yeah, that part of the quote regarding performance of section flow should be excluded from general COBOL considerations and is pretty tightly bound to the implementation.